# Access 2010. SQL "This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated."

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT TO_DO_LIST.[Description of Event], TO_DO_LIST.[Date of Event]
FROM TO_DO_LIST
WHERE (((TO_DO_LIST.[Date of Event])=[Forms]![Form3]![ComboMonth] & "/" & [Forms]![form3]![txt2] & "/" & [Forms]![form3]![ComboYear]))
ORDER BY TO_DO_LIST.Importance;
```

This code was written to try and get the text from our `TO_DO_LIST` to show in the selected text box in our form (A calendar in Access).

It works, but we keep getting this error

> "This expression is typed incorrectly, or is too complex to be
>   evaluated. For example a numeric expression may contain too many
>   complicated elements. Try to simplify the expression by assigning
>   parts of the expression to variables"

Any way to rewrite this code to make this pop up go away?

Comment: Perhaps try `TO_DO_LIST.[Date of Event] = DateSerial([Forms]![form3]![ComboYear], [Forms]![Form3]![ComboMonth], [Forms]![form3]![txt2])`

Comment: Thank you. The code works,I believe that the error is popping up in the cases where there are dates without events in our TO_DO_LIST